Apple Numbers RegEx not working as expected (Negative lookahead)
RegEx.Extract Negative lookahead help needed due to what works in RegEx Support website does not work in Apple Numbers
(?<=XYZ((?!\d+).)*)\d+
This is invoice from company XYZ - 1234545 product name , product number 444456, information invoice unit cost $12.0 and invoice total $1343.00
Another company may have following invoice 
This is invoice from company ABC - 1234545 product name and information invoice total cost $6777 and invoice unit cost $654
. I have to create another expression for the result to be the match instead of the group. (?<=XYZ.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?)\d+ which assumes XYZ not more than 10 characters away from number. How to improve such that XYZ can be any number of characters away from number?

Does this answer your question? regex to find non-price consecutive digits not immediately after certain word for Apple Numbers
